# How to Intercept express redirect request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a use case where I want to redirect the client requests to `https://ifconfig.co/json` to get some info, but before I send the response back to the client I need to transform it

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.redirect('https://ifconfig.co/json')
})
```

is there a way to intercept the redirect response or any workaround that I can use?

Comment: why do you want to redirect the user? use axios to fetch the needed data and then respond the client directly after your transformation.

Comment: If I did so, I will get the server details instead of the client's

Comment: Aha, Sorry didn't see the url. I don't think you can redirect user back the server again unless that website gets url and redirects it back to you, however you can have all the information that you want. you can get client's user agent, Ip and everything else that websites provides except the location, so just try to find an api to post the IP and check where it comes from.

`req.get('User-Agent')` and `req.ip`

Comment: I found a workaround by querying the IP address, I just want to make sure if there is a way to intercept the redirection response.

Comment: @카림사부 No, there is no way to intercept that. You're telling the browser via the HTTP response to go ifconfig.co instead, at that point your server is no longer involved in anything.